# Questions about golang's rand package

Tags: go, random

I've been using and reading about the Golang rand package but I can't find a resource that actually explains what it's doing in a way I can understand.

First, what is really happening when you "seed"? If you are then asking for a random number in a range (for example using rand.Intn(7)), it seems like that should be enough to tell Go what you're looking for, but it's not. **What does rand.Seed() contribute?**

Here is an example that you can play with [here](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-randseed-function-in-golang#:%7E:text=the%20seed%20value.-,Example,-The%20code%20given):

```
func main() {
  rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
  fmt.Println(rand.Intn(7))
}
```

I was thinking maybe the "Source" is all possible numbers you could pull from and then something like rand.Intn() gives you a random number from a subset of the Source. So seeding is just defining the Source. But if I try getting a random number from a range outside of the initial seed, it stills works, so that doesn't seem to be right, unless it just excludes the part of the range that doesn't exist. See this example:

```
func main() {
  rand.Seed(6)
  fmt.Println(rand.Intn(7))
}
```

And what about this [line](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#Seed:%7E:text=If%20Seed%20is%20not%20called%2C%20the%20generator%20is%20seeded%20randomly%20at%20program%20startup.) in the documentation that says:

> If Seed is not called, the generator is seeded randomly at program startup.

That doesn't seem to happen because if you don't call rand.Seed() and try to use rand.Intn(), you just get the same thing over and over, similar to if you use a constant with rand.Seed().

Second, the documentation for rand.Intn() [says](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#Intn:%7E:text=the%20default%20Source.-,It%20panics%20if%20n%20%3C%3D%200.,-Example%20%C2%B6) it "panics if n <= 0". I've tested this using the above link and it's not true, it will return 0 without panicking. I actually want to include 0 so this is good but it's not lining up with what the docs say. Is there another, proper way to include 0 when specifying a range? I couldn't find one.

Third, the documentation talks about a "default Source" [here](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#Seed:%7E:text=value%20to%20initialize-,the%20default%20Source,-to%20a%20deterministic). Is that just something that exists without us having to do anything? And then if I want a specific Source I use rand.New() to create one? Why would I want a specific one?

Go's documentation is considered very good and well thought out so I think I must just be missing something here, appreciate anyone's insight!

Comment: Actually Go's package rand, its integer pseudorandom generator and how its seeded is absolute standard and basically works the same like any other mainstream language. You might want to read about what a _pseudo_random number generator is.

Answer (score 3):

The `math/rand` random number generator is a "pseudo" random number generator. Conceptually, it looks like this:

```
var last int

func nextRandom() int { 
   last:= computeRandom(last)
   return last
}
```

So it is a deterministic function that generates a sequence of values based on the previous value. Given an initial value of `last`, consecutive calls to `nextRandom` will generate the same sequence of values.

`Seed` sets the `last` value, so by setting the last value to some number, say, current time, you get a different sequence of numbers.

As of this writing (v1.19), the random number generator is *not* seeded with a random number at program startup. This seems to have changed at v1.20.

`Intn` panics when `n<=0`: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.2:src/math/rand/rand.go;l=178

The default source is a package level `Source` instance used by all exported functions:

```
var globalRand = New(new(lockedSource))

func Int63() int64 { return globalRand.Int63() }
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! A couple follow up questions:

Can you see this sequence of values anywhere? What is the relationship between those values and values in a range returned by `rand.Intn()?`

So, is the documentation just wrong? Or am I understanding it wrong? It says: `If Seed is not called, the generator is seeded randomly at program startup.`

In your example on panic, it says `if n <= 0` so I don't understand why you say it panics when `n<0`.

Thank you!

Comment: `Intn` will simply limit the max returned value, something like: `Int()%n`. I do not see where seed is initialized, the documentation appears to be wrong (maybe someone can correct me?). It panics when n<=0, I fixed the answer.

Comment: @JimB Thank you! I see this line: "The math/rand package now automatically seeds the global random number generator (used by top-level functions like Float64 and Int) with a random value", so the confusion is still there for me because it doesn't seem to be doing this. I assume "top level functions" are the functions in the `rand` package (not the methods)? Google doesn't really give me anything about what those are. If that's the case, it sounds like you shouldn't need to seed anything if you use `rand.Intn()` for example.

Comment: @JimB Also not sure where to find the `globalRand` function, it doesn't appear on the page you linked to or in the `rand` package, could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: @gabriellend, just search for the function in the source if you’re curious to see it, but the package internals don’t really matter for this question because the package does does what the documentation says it does.

Comment: @JimB I found it, thank you! But...it doesn't seem to be doing what it says it does i.e. automatically seeding...

Comment: @gabriellend, sorry, you have to follow the code a little further to the `lockedSource.source` method. It needs to be configurable because the seeding behavior can be turned off with GODEBUG.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for following up. I still don't really get it but maybe it's just too complex for me at the moment and I'll come back to it later. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

> What does rand.Seed() contribute?

Seeding a pseudo random number generator means providing input that sets it state. A pseudo random number generator then creates randomness from that state. If you seed the PRNG multiple times then the later seed values get mixed in.

> I was thinking maybe the "Source" is all possible numbers you could pull from and then something like rand.Intn() gives you a random number from a subset of the Source.

The Source is really a limited RNG in the sense that it only produces bits (or, in this case, integer values in the range [0, 2^63), which of course simply corresponds with 63 bits. That can then be used to perform other jobs, such as generating numbers in other ranges, or maybe to shuffle a list, etc.

> That doesn't seem to happen because if you don't call rand.Seed() and try to use rand.Intn(), you just get the same thing over and over, similar to if you use a constant with rand.Seed().

This [seems to be a recent change](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/54880). So I guess your runtime and documentation are not for the same API version.

> Second, the documentation for rand.Intn() says it "panics if n <= 0". I've tested this using the above link and it's not true, it will return 0 without panicking.

Sounds like a bug to me. If `n` is indeed 0 or lower than 0 then it should panic.

> I actually want to include 0 so this is good but it's not lining up with what the docs say. Is there another, proper way to include 0 when specifying a range? I couldn't find one.

Not sure what you mean here. If you'd specify 0 then you get the range [0, 0) which doesn't make any sense, as 0 is first included as start value, and then excluded as end value. You'd expect [0, 1) also to be problematic as just returning 0 is not very random (I'd still allow for the function as API designer, but yeah, it's a degenerate case).

rand.Intn() generates a range [0, n). Whatever `n` is going to be, 0 is going to be included in the possible output.

> Third, the documentation talks about a "default Source" here. Is that just something that exists without us having to do anything? And then if I want a specific Source I use rand.New() to create one? Why would I want a specific one?

Well, maybe you want to create a very specific run of test values that doesn't change, e.g. for testing purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much! There is a lot here so I'm going to need some time to digest it. I can tell you I thought [0, n) meant exclusive/inclusive so now I understand why 0 is included regarding that notation and that explains why you were confused. Still, you and the docs say "If n is indeed 0 or lower than 0 then it should panic", yet 0 is included? How does that make sense?

Comment: Also, now I have the inverse problem. I'm seeing n still being included in my code. It's what I want, I have an array that I'm pulling random images from and I want to include all of them, but it's not what the docs say should happen. Would the "proper" way to do that be giving rand.Intn() a number that is one larger than the length of the array?

Comment: Yes, but taking a look at the code of the function then `n` should indeed not be included (Burak has shown that by directly linking to the source), so I would like to see some proof in code for that.

Comment: Thank you! I think I know what's going on now! As an example, I had an array with 14 items and I called rand.Intn(14). I was already implementing the fix I suggested, I just totally forgot about 0 indexes for a sec! Great, so glad that's cleared up! Still not sure why `rand.Intn()` doesn't panic when zero comes up, you can test that in the little playground link I have in the post.

Comment: Ah! I've got it! I was misunderstanding the documentation. It shouldn't panic when 0 is returned by `rand.Intn(n)`, but when `n = 0`! Thank you for your input that triggered these discoveries.

Comment: I was wondering if you meant output instead of input, but really, you cannot panic & return 0 so I thought... nah. Glad you're getting it now though.